# Too few parameters, expected 4;

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Dim query As String
query = "insert into tbl_passenger(passenger_name,age,gender_id,address,phone_no,plane_no,seat_no,destination_id,time_id,price_id)values('" & _
Me.txtpassengername.Value & "'," & Me.txtage.Value & "," & Me.cmbgender.Column(1) & ",'" & Me.txtaddress.Value & "', " & Me.txtphone.Value & "," & _
Me.cmbplane.Column(1) & "," & Me.cmbseat.Column(1) & "," & Me.cmbdestination.Column(1) & "," & Me.cmbtime.Column(1) & "," & _
Me.cmbprice.Column(1) & ")"

CurrentDb.Execute (query)
MsgBox ("Data Inserted")
```

What is the problem here? The error I get is

> Too few parameters, expected 4;

Comment: Do you need to use column(0) for some of your combo boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Insert a debug line:

```
Debug.Print query
CurrentDb.Execute (query)
MsgBox ("Data Inserted")
```

Study what you see, and you will know. Or post the output here.